# How does GT5 combine the two Spec-B experience levels?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

In Spec-B mode, I have noticed that when both "I" and my driver were at level 0, the driver could barely drive in a straight line. Now that I'm level 35, I can create a level 0 driver who can win any race straight away if I give him a sufficiently fast car (like the Formula Gran Tursmo F1 car).

So, my question is this: how exactly does GT5 combine 'my' Spec-B (significant) experience level with that of the AI driver (who may have no experience) in order to allow the AI driver to leap-frog his way to a much higher level? It seems to make the experience level of the AI driver almost irrelevant.

Thanks!

Comment: I found the same, I swapped a lv9 driver for a brand new lv 0 driver, when I was lv19, jumped him into my 718bhp Ferrari 458 Italia and he aced a race, low physical at the end though.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't experiment with Spec-B much, but I believe I got to level 12 or so and I found that your level is much more important than the driver. I had a few drivers (one aggressive, one slightly less aggressive, one more averaged) and I found that the higher level I got, the drivers level mattered much less... My lvl 6 driver was barely any better than my level 2 driver. Even at just level 12. I now want to go experiment with this more now. They ran out of mental energy much less than physical energy I noticed though.